# Value of SMD capacitor

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount

How do I know the value of this capacitor?:
The case shows "E0001", "68", and "35k".

[image: capacitor]

When measuring, it shows 84uF (I measured two of the same value). But I can't  see any indication of this value on the case of the capacitor.

Answer (score 3):

I'd assume that it is 68 uF.  When you measure the value of a component in-circuit, the measured value will be affected by other components in the circuit, so the measured value is not reliable.

Also, electrolytic capacitors usually have a fairly large tolerance - perhaps +50/-10%, so your 84 uF might be valid.

Comment: The 35 is the voltage rating.

Comment: I'd say the "K" means it's a KEMET cap, as it's a common manufacturer, but it doesn't have the top and bottom markers like the KEMET mark usually does.

Comment: Like Peter and Collin said - it's 68uF / 35V electrolytic capacitor. Probably made by Samwha, here's datasheet: http://www.samwha.com/electric/product/list_pdf2/sc.pdf

Comment: EDIT: Wrong datasheet, here's the correct one (for CK series): http://www.samwha.com/electric/product/list_pdf2/CK.pdf